# Extract By Mask gives Raster Horizontal Shift

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, snapping, extract-by-mask, mosaic-dataset

Is there a way to snap a raster/DEM to a mosaic dataset?

I am using the Extract By Mask tool in ArcGIS Pro on a mosaic dataset. The output raster's cell values do not match the original mosaic dataset it came from. The cells seem to have shifted after the Extract By Mask Tool was run. The only way I know how to fix this problem is by changing "Snap Raster" in Environments, but have not yet found a way to snap a raster to a mosaic dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I have a process (hack) that I use for this contingency, get some sort of worlded image like a bitmap (any file, size and content don't matter) and create a [world file](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/General/topics/author_world_files.htm) (.bpw in the case of .bmp, .jgw in the case of .jpg but avoid using TIFF files as the world file argues with the geotags in a GeoTIFF) and adjust the last two lines manually, in your favorite text editor, to the origin you desire and set the cell size (line 1 and 4 but make sure line 4 is negative) to whatever you need and use that file as your [snap raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/snap-raster.htm) and [output cell size](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/cell-size.htm).

Comment: This sounds like an interesting workaround! How do you go about getting a bitmap?

Comment: There's bound to be dozens of them just lying around in your filesystem, do a search on your system drive for *.bmp (Windows) and you'll get plenty of results, copy one to a specific location and then create a new bpw file (you might need to turn on extensions for known file types to do this) in the same folder and edit with Notepad (or any other text editor).